# Add shortcut SQL management studio 2008 to select top 1000 order by PK desc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

when I right click a table I can select `select top 1000 rows` and `edit top 200 rows`
I'd like to add an option `select bottom 1000 rows`

I am pretty sure that I've seen it somewhere online how to do this. But I can't remember where...

already found this: http://sqlserver-training.com/how-to-change-default-value-of-select-or-edit-top-rows-in-ssms-2008/- 
but it seems impossible to add a template query...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593047/mssql-server-management-studio-ssms-2005-new-query-template  This is for SQL 2005 but perhaps it is what you are seeking for SQL 2008 mgt studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried SSMS Tools Pack?  http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/  This should be able to do exactly what you need, and more.  Specifically, look at the "Running custom scripts from object explorer" feature listed on the home page.